# How to intercept HTTPS API calls?

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, server, proxy, interceptor

I have one `nodejs` and one `spring boot` application. From the browser, I hit the end point of the `node` application. From there, I hit a `spring` end point. The `spring` then calls a third-party API, which is using `https`. I want to track all the end calls and responses in the journey. especially the call from `spring` to a third-party API. Which tool can I use?

I've already used `wireshark`, `https toolkit` and `charles proxy` but I was only able to capture calls from the browser to the backend. But I want to capture the backend-to-backend requests as well.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool are considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can find more information about it in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: if spring boot, take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Comment: @JCompetence I was looking for a tool actually

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture backend-to-backend traffic, there is no really straightforward way. However, you can set up [mitm proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) in one of your services and see the traffic on the hosted UI.

PS - When you deploy the MITM proxy, make sure you don't deploy on the production environment. It could be risky as it may not be able to handle the production traffic.

Comment: Hi, i've tried to use mitm but seems like they don't catch any localhost requests. Do I need to do anything additional to make this work?

Comment: @Araf You can use any tool like Charles Proxy, Wireshark, or ToolKit to listen to your local traffic. You can use MITM in your backend services on your dev/qa/staging setup.

Comment: I've tried to use MITM but it wasn't catching any backend calls. My scenario is, I'm running both nodejs and spring servers on local machine. they communicate with each other locally. but the spring server calls a third party API. I need to intercept that. how can i configure mitm to do that?